# "which Foucault is described as seeking…"

Tags: relative-clauses

*In support of this morbid diagnosis, Miller paints a lurid picture of a man obsessed by death and drugs, suicide and sadomasochistic sex which Foucault is described as seeking right up until his death in the bath houses in New York and San Francisco.*

http://www.contempaesthetics.org/newvolume/pages/article.php?articleID=463

Do you not think that the preposition "in" is missing before "which". I suppose that the subordinate clause modifies the noun "picture". Without "in" it would be in my opinion better "which describes Foucault as…".

Comment: No. The relative clause refers to *death and drugs, suicide and sadomasochistic sex*, which is the direct object of *seeking*: "Foucault is described as seeking death and drugs, suicide and sadomasochistic sex right up until his death..."

Comment: You *could* include the word ***in*** there, but this would affect the syntax (and meaning, to a lesser extent). As it stands, Foucault is described as *seeking death and drugs, suicide and sadomasochistic sex* until he died, but *in principle*, that description might have been provided by someone other than Miller (or indeed, by society at large). I might prefer a comma after ***sex*** to help the reader parse the somewhat convoluted syntax, but it's perfectly valid. If you included ***in*** it would be unambiguous that the description is manifest *specifically* in the picture Miller paints.

Comment: (I'll assume your cited writer didn't intend to imply that Foucault actually sought such a lurid picture as that painted by Miller, but *in principle* that reading could apply, so far as the syntax is concerned. Come to that, Foucault might even have been seeking ***a man obsessed*** by [death, drugs, etc.].)

Comment: The part "which Foucault is described…" confused me. It it were "which Foucault – as is described – was seeking right up until his death…" it would be more transparent for me in terms of syntax.

Comment: Think of interpolating the Agent of *describe*: *...which Foucault is described by Miller as seeking...*. In active voice, *... which Foucault describes Miller as seeking ...*

Comment: "which Foucault describes Miller as seeking…? I am surprised by the word order. The construction "which Foucault Millers describes as seeking" is ungrammatical here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Miller paints a lurid picture of a man 
     obsessed by death and drugs, suicide and sadomasochistic sex 
         which Foucault is described as seeking 
            right up until his death
                  in the bath houses in New York and San Francisco.
```

... which Foucault [the man so depicted] is described as seeking ...

I would reorder so:

```
 Miller paints a lurid picture of a man 
     obsessed by death and drugs, suicide and sadomasochistic sex 
         which Foucault is described as seeking 
             in the bath houses in  [of] New York and San Francisco
                 right up until his death
```

The pattern is:

<sup>**which** [i.e. which grammatical objects] [subject] **is described as** [PRESENT PARTICIPLE OF TRANSITIVE VERB]</sup>

... routes, which the tax driver is described as taking....

... herbs, which the chef is described as using ...

... songs, which the soprano is described as singing ...

... inventions, which the inventor is described as inventing ....

... cars, which the salesman is described as selling ...

The present participle of the transitive verb could be replaced with **having** plus the past participle:

... routes, which the tax driver is described as having taken....

... herbs, which the chef is described as having used ...

... songs, which the soprano is described as having sung ...

... inventions, which the inventor is described as having invented ....

... cars, which the salesman is described as having sold ...

> ... death and drugs, suicide and sadomasochistic sex which Foucault is
>   described as having sought...